# How to save JSON to a file without \ and ""?

Tags: python, json

my.json contains:

```
{"something": [{"a": "b", "c": "", "d": ""}]}
```

appendJson is a string with clean Json:

```
{"a": "b", "b": "", "a": ""}
```

the undesired output is:

```
{"something": [{"a": "b", "a": "", "b": ""}, {"a": "b", "b": "", "a": ""}, "{\\"a\\": \\"1\\", \\"a\\": \\"a\\", \\"b\\": \\"\\"}"]}
```

while it should be:

```
{"something": [{"a": "b", "a": "", "b": ""}, {"a": "b", "b": "", "a": ""}, {"a": "1", "a": "a", "b": ""}]}
```

Using `json.dump`, which is ran only once in the whole script, the following code (appendjson is being passed as a parameter as a string with clean json):

```
with open('my.json', 'r') as file:
   data = file.read()
myjson = json.loads(data)
myjson['something'].append(appendJson)
with open('my.json', 'w') as outfile:
   json.dump(myjson, outfile)
```

outputs with a lot of escape characters and `""`. How to avoid the escape characters unnecessary quotes associated with the `json.dump` or how to save that to a file without "`cannot save dict into file`" errors?

The goal is to have clean json inside the file, without any \\ "" over my list elements as you see below. So how to avoid this in my case?:
{"something": [{"a": "b", "a": "", "b": ""}, {"a": "b", "b": "", "a": ""}, "{\"a\": \"1\", \"a\": \"a\", \"b\": \"\"}"]}

Comment: It wouldn't be valid json without the quotes and escapes. I don't think it's reasonable to expect the json module to support invalid json.

Comment: What is `appendJson`? I suspect this may already be JSON-encoded, that's why you're getting unexpected escaped quotes. You should append an ordinary object to `myjson`, not a JSON string.

Comment: Without including `appendJson`, the code included in the question is not sufficient to reproduce the problem. To have a proper [mre], it would be helpful to just hardcode your input values (instead of reading them from files at all); that way nobody needs anything that isn't already present in your question to be able to generate the stated output.

Comment: You're saying the quotes and \ are _unneccessary_? There may be differences between how the file is stored (and viewed in a text editor), how it appears if you `print()` it in python, and how it appears if you store it in a variable and echo that variable by typing it on a separate line in the interactive Python REPL. The text editor should show legal JSON, where the quotes & slashes are strictly necessary, and the `print()` should mirror that but may have variations if you altered the file during read. The value echoed on cmd line may have extra escapes. Note where the extra characters are.

Comment: No the file should be regular json, not json with quotes and backslashes

Comment: appendJson is a clean Json string like  {"a": "b", "b": "", "a": ""}

Comment: @kol23, that's the problem -- you shouldn't be appending the **JSON string** `{"a": "b", "b": "", "a": ""}`; instead, you should be appending the **Python object** `{"a": "b", "b": "", "a": ""}`. When you append something that's already a JSON string to a value you're going to be putting through a JSON serializer, it gets converted to JSON twice, so you have the extra escapes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with
`newjson=[x.strip() for x in newjson]`
right after reading the file.

Answer (score 1):

What is `appendJson`? If it's already JSON, then calling `json.dump` on it again will cause the extra quotes and escape characters you mention. Make sure you're only serializing your data once.

```py
>>> python_dict = {"a": "A","b":"B"}
>>> json_string = json.dumps(python_dict)
>>> json_string
'{"a": "A", "b": "B"}'
>>> double_json = json.dumps(json_string)
>>> double_json
'"{\\"a\\": \\"A\\", \\"b\\": \\"B\\"}"'
```

Comment: Json.dump is called only once, hence this does not apply here

Comment: @koller23 this was an illustration of what happens if you call `json.dump` on something that's already encoded as json. I'm speculating a bit because there isn't enough information in the question about what `appendJson` is to provide a more specific answer. Can you update the code sample in your question with enough detail to replicate the problem?

Comment: appendJson is a clean json string like  {"a": "b", "b": "", "a": ""}